# Javascript - I have an Uncaught TypeError for my game with inner.html

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner with Javascript, only starting this week. And I am trying to learn it with games.

I tried to make a traditional shifumi (Rock, paper, scissors), with a Javascript file separate of my HTML file. The code worked when it was part of the HTML file.

the error is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

the subject of the problem :

```
  var joueur = buttons[i].innerHTML;
```

[image]

I don't know how I can do...
If anyone can help me ... You make me happy :) :) :)

CélineI

Answer (score 0):

In your for-loop, replace `var` with `let`:

```
for (let i = 0; ...
```

The difference is that with `var` you pass a reference to the very same variable into all loops, which, at the end of the loop, will evaluate to `buttons.length`. Because `NodeList`s like what you get from `querySelectorAll` are 0-indexed, there never is an element with that index.

With `let`, each iteration of your loop has its own instance of the counter variable.

Example:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() { console.log(i) });
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<button>button</button>
<button>button</button>
```

Same with `let` instead of `var`:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() { console.log(i) });
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<button>button</button>
<button>button</button>
```